# phpMyAdmin: Valid SQL --> View, Fails with "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: mysql, view

I am working in phpMyAdmin. I have a query which executes successfully and returns exactly what I want. When I create a View with the same query, the View gets created successfully. However, only when I try to SELECT from the View, I get the following error:

```html
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Here is my View create script:

```html
CREATE VIEW games_v
AS
[query];
```

Here is the query in its entirety:

```html
SELECT g.game_id,
g.sport_id,
g.season_id,
g.date,
g.away_team_id,
IFNULL(sa.name, g.away_team_name) away_team_name,
sa.city away_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.away_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) away_division,
(SELECT sl.league_id FROM school_leagues sl
 WHERE g.sport_id = sl.sport_id
 AND g.season_id BETWEEN sl.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sl.end_season_id,100)
 AND g.away_team_id = sl.school_id) away_league_id,
(SELECT sl.league_div_id FROM school_leagues sl
 WHERE g.sport_id = sl.sport_id
 AND g.season_id BETWEEN sl.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sl.end_season_id,100)
 AND g.away_team_id = sl.school_id) away_league_div_id,
(SELECT sd.district_id FROM school_districts sd
WHERE g.sport_id = sd.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN sd.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sd.end_season_id,100)
AND g.away_team_id = sd.school_id) away_district_id,
g.home_team_id,
IFNULL(sh.name, g.home_team_name) home_team_name,
sh.city home_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.home_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) home_division,
(SELECT sl.league_id FROM school_leagues sl
 WHERE g.sport_id = sl.sport_id
 AND g.season_id BETWEEN sl.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sl.end_season_id,100)
 AND g.home_team_id = sl.school_id) home_league_id,
(SELECT sl.league_div_id FROM school_leagues sl
 WHERE g.sport_id = sl.sport_id
 AND g.season_id BETWEEN sl.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sl.end_season_id,100)
 AND g.home_team_id = sl.school_id) home_league_div_id,
(SELECT sd.district_id FROM school_districts sd
WHERE g.sport_id = sd.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN sd.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sd.end_season_id,100)
AND g.home_team_id = sd.school_id) home_district_id,
(
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN sla.league_id != slh.league_id THEN 'N'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) = IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN 'Y'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) != IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN ld.div_only = 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END FROM league_divisions ld WHERE ld.league_id = sla.league_id LIMIT 1)
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM school_leagues sla, school_leagues slh
WHERE g.sport_id = sla.sport_id
AND g.away_team_id = sla.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN sla.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sla.end_season_id, 100)
AND g.sport_id = slh.sport_id
AND g.home_team_id = slh.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN slh.start_season_id AND IFNULL(slh.end_season_id, 100)
) league_game,
g.location,
g.type,
g.time,
g.away_score,
g.home_score
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN schools sa ON sa.school_id = g.away_team_id
LEFT JOIN schools sh ON sh.school_id = g.home_team_id
```

Again, the query by itself runs fine. But when I try to SELECT from a View that was created using that query, it fails with the above error.

I am an Oracle developer, so I apologize in advance if some of my inline SQL statements could have been achieved without being inline. I'm not used to using the terms LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, etc. I'm used to just using (+) for Outer Joins in Oracle, so I just went the easy (yet inefficient) route, I'm sure.

RESOLVED! Here's the code... Per my comment below, I just added a few more tables to my JOIN section (LEFT/OUTER join), and it works. Not sure what it was in some of my inline SELECTs, but it seems to be working now.

```html
SELECT g.game_id,
g.sport_id,
g.season_id,
g.date,
g.away_team_id,
IFNULL(sa.name, g.away_team_name) away_team_name,
sa.city away_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.away_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) away_division,
sla.league_id away_league_id,
sla.league_div_id away_league_div_id,
sda.district_id away_district_id,
g.home_team_id,
IFNULL(sh.name, g.home_team_name) home_team_name,
sh.city home_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.home_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) home_division,
slh.league_id home_league_id,
slh.league_div_id home_league_div_id,
sdh.district_id home_district_id,
(
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN sla.league_id != slh.league_id THEN 'N'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) = IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN 'Y'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) != IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN ld.div_only = 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END FROM league_divisions ld WHERE ld.league_id = sla.league_id LIMIT 1)
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM school_leagues sla, school_leagues slh
WHERE g.sport_id = sla.sport_id
AND g.away_team_id = sla.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN sla.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sla.end_season_id, 100)
AND g.sport_id = slh.sport_id
AND g.home_team_id = slh.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN slh.start_season_id AND IFNULL(slh.end_season_id, 100)
) league_game,
g.location,
g.type,
g.time,
g.away_score,
g.home_score
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN schools sa ON sa.school_id = g.away_team_id
LEFT JOIN schools sh ON sh.school_id = g.home_team_id
LEFT JOIN school_districts sda ON sda.school_id = g.away_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sda.start_season_id AND sda.end_season_id AND g.sport_id = sda.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_districts sdh ON sdh.school_id = g.home_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sdh.start_season_id AND sdh.end_season_id AND g.sport_id = sdh.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_leagues sla ON sla.school_id = g.away_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sla.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sla.end_season_id,100) AND g.sport_id = sla.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_leagues slh ON slh.school_id = g.home_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN slh.start_season_id AND IFNULL(slh.end_season_id,100) AND g.sport_id = slh.sport_id
```

Comment: I have solved my problem. After I had more time to look at the query, I added a few more tables to my outer join list, and it works. I have not completed all of them, yet, but the ones that I fixed seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I removed some more unnecessary inline SELECT statements and instead added a few more outer/left joins to the bottom of the query. I'm not sure what it was in the inline queries that was causing it to fail, but it seems to be working now.

What it comes down to is this - me being an Oracle developer, I expected a more descriptive error when the SQL filed (maybe "More than one record returned" or something), but the generic error here really stumped me. Haha. (and when I ran the SQL before creating the view, I even validated the count(*), and it was correct, which is why I originally ruled out errors like that)

```html
SELECT g.game_id,
g.sport_id,
g.season_id,
g.date,
g.away_team_id,
IFNULL(sa.name, g.away_team_name) away_team_name,
sa.city away_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.away_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) away_division,
sla.league_id away_league_id,
sla.league_div_id away_league_div_id,
sda.district_id away_district_id,
g.home_team_id,
IFNULL(sh.name, g.home_team_name) home_team_name,
sh.city home_city,
(SELECT de.division_id FROM division_enrollment de, school_enrollment se, sports s
WHERE g.sport_id = s.sport_id
AND s.gender = se.gender
AND g.home_team_id = se.school_id
AND g.sport_id = IFNULL(se.sport_id,g.sport_id)
AND g.season_id BETWEEN se.start_year AND se.end_year
AND g.sport_id = de.sport_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN de.start_year AND de.end_year
AND se.enrollment BETWEEN de.min_enrollment AND de.max_enrollment) home_division,
slh.league_id home_league_id,
slh.league_div_id home_league_div_id,
sdh.district_id home_district_id,
(
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN sla.league_id != slh.league_id THEN 'N'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) = IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN 'Y'
    WHEN sla.league_id = slh.league_id AND IFNULL(sla.league_div_id,1) != IFNULL(slh.league_div_id,1) THEN (SELECT CASE WHEN ld.div_only = 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END FROM league_divisions ld WHERE ld.league_id = sla.league_id LIMIT 1)
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM school_leagues sla, school_leagues slh
WHERE g.sport_id = sla.sport_id
AND g.away_team_id = sla.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN sla.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sla.end_season_id, 100)
AND g.sport_id = slh.sport_id
AND g.home_team_id = slh.school_id
AND g.season_id BETWEEN slh.start_season_id AND IFNULL(slh.end_season_id, 100)
) league_game,
g.location,
g.type,
g.time,
g.away_score,
g.home_score
FROM games g
LEFT JOIN schools sa ON sa.school_id = g.away_team_id
LEFT JOIN schools sh ON sh.school_id = g.home_team_id
LEFT JOIN school_districts sda ON sda.school_id = g.away_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sda.start_season_id AND sda.end_season_id AND g.sport_id = sda.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_districts sdh ON sdh.school_id = g.home_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sdh.start_season_id AND sdh.end_season_id AND g.sport_id = sdh.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_leagues sla ON sla.school_id = g.away_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN sla.start_season_id AND IFNULL(sla.end_season_id,100) AND g.sport_id = sla.sport_id
LEFT JOIN school_leagues slh ON slh.school_id = g.home_team_id AND g.season_id BETWEEN slh.start_season_id AND IFNULL(slh.end_season_id,100) AND g.sport_id = slh.sport_id
```